# awk / gawk asorti() problem

Tags: linux, unix, awk, lexicographic, asort

I've got following problem with gawk's asorti function:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{ \

  a[1]=6; \

  a[2]=7; \

  a[3]=8; \

  a[21]=9; \

  a[123]=10; \

  t=asorti(a, o); \

  for (i=1; i<=t; i++) { \

    print i,o[i]; \

  } \

}'
```

The result is:

```
1 1

2 123

3 2

4 21

5 3
```

So it's pretty clear awk, sorted indices in lexicographical order, but awk's doc says (asort(s[, d])):

> "The contents of s are sorted using gawk’s normal rules for comparing values..."

However, when I copy indices itself into temp array, and sort that new array using asort(),

it seems ok (using something like):

```
j=1; for(e in a) { temp[j++] = e; }
```

Am I DOIN-IT-WRONG, or is it problem with gawk's asorti() ?

Comment: Your awk script is enclosed in single quotes, so you don't need the backslashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [gawk manual](http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/gawk.html#Numeric-Array-Subscripts): "An important aspect about arrays to remember is that *array subscripts are always strings.*"

Answer (score 4):

I know there were limitations on gawk 3, but on gawk 4 (at least on 4.1.1) it's trivial:

```
t=asorti(a, o, "@ind_num_asc");
```

Comment: You saved my entire life! didn't noticed 3rd argument in asorti. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you could use something like this (you may need to adjust the padding):

```
gawk 'BEGIN { 
  a[1] = 6; a[2] = 7; a[3] = 8; a[21] = 9; a[123] = 10; 
  for (i in a) io[sprintf("%15s", i)] = a[i]
  t = asorti(io, o)
  for (i = 0; ++i <= t;) print i, o[i] + 0
    }'
```

With Gnu awk you can even preserve the original keys/indexes:

```
WHINY_USERS=oops gawk 'BEGIN { 
  a[1]=6; a[2]=7; a[3]=8; a[21]=9; a[123]=10; 
  for (i in a) o[sprintf("%15s", i)] = a[i]
  for (i in o) print i + 0, o[i]
    }'
```

Comment: Formatting the index with `sprintf` was godsend on the handful of servers I can't upgrade gawk on. Thank you!